# in the Linux command line, how do i check if the contents of a file1 exist in file2? Then find out where the similar patterns exist in file2?

Tags: linux, terminal

i need to take a txt file that looks like this:

```
3   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   2   2   2   2   1   2   2   2   2   1   2   2   2   2   2   1   2   2   2   2   1   2   2   2   2   1   2   2   1   1   1   1   3   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   X   X   X
```

and check to see if that pattern exists in a larger file that looks like this:

```
1001        VV01        CH01    T   d01 KJKSC01 -   -   -   C01 5945    3720    -2225   36  -66.3   36C 36C1_OOB    BD1A    BD8B    DTC_TRFC01  DTCC04  102 119         1001    3   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   2   2   2   2   1   2   2   2   2   1   2   2   2   2   2   1   2   2   2   2   1   2   2   2   2   1   2   2   1   1   1   1   3   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   X   X   X   0   2   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
1002        Sf01        CH01    T   d01 KEMEC01 -   -   -   CS4 5945    3720    -2225   36  -66.3   36C 36C1_OOB    BD1A    BD8B    DTC_TRFC01  HWNA04  102 119         1002    3   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   3   3   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   2   2   2   2   1   2   2   2   2   1   2   2   2   3   1   3   2   2   2   2   1   2   2   2   2   1   2   2   1   1   1   1   3   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   X   X   X   0   2   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
1003        SD01        CH01    N   d01 JSNFC01 -   -   -   C05 5945    3720    -2225   36  -66.3   36C 36C1_OOB    BD1A    BD8B    DTC_TRFC01  JSHG04  102 119         1003    3   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   3   1   1   3   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   2   2   2   2   1   2   2   2   2   1   2   2   2   3   1   2   3   2   2   2   1   2   2   2   2   1   2   2   1   1   1   1   3   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   X   X   X   0   2   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

then once the pattern is found, i need to print the "1001" found before the matching pattern at the beginning of the row. (there are about 100 of these rows in file2)

I've tried a few things:

```
grep -Pc -f file1 file 2
```

then

```
grep -P -f file1 file2 | awk '{print \$1}'
```

to grab the matching pattern.

However

```
grep -Pc -f file1 file2
```

wouldn't find the pattern unless i used

```
grep -Pc -f <(tr -d '\t\n\r' <file1) <(tr -d '\t\n\r' <file2)
```

which took out all the white spaces but then made it hard to find the "1001" that i needed to pull to tell me which pattern i have found.

I'm sorry if this has already been answered. I spent a few days reading and trying other questions that are on the site but I'm very inexperienced and nothing seemed to work.

Thanks in advance to any advice or help!

Comment: This is easier to do using `awk`.

Comment: could you provide an example? or maybe a link to how i could use awk? 
thanks!

Comment: I wrote an answer, but then I saw in the question that the whitespace doesn't match between the two files. That makes it more complicated and my answer wouldn't work.

Comment: oh no thats my miscommunication. the white space is the same. that was just a result of something i tried.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `awk`

```
awk -v pat=$(cat file1) '$0 ~ pat { print $1 }' file2
```